# Is it possible to store a stored procedure in SQL Server database and call it every minute again and again?

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to store a stored procedure in a SQL Server database and call it every minute again and again, using SQL Server, not the software? And if so - how can I do this?

Comment: Now that you have a good answer from @lad2025, I'm curious as to why you want to run the SP every min.  What problem does this solve?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, **SQL Server Agent** can run jobs based on specific time or interval.

[Creating SQL Server Job](http://sqlserverscribbles.com/2013/06/08/how-to-create-sql-server-agent-jobs/)

SSMS -> SQL Server Agent -> Right-Click -> New Job -> Select Name, Database, Code and Schedule

When you finish you can click `Script` button and get script that create job (if needed).

You can also start Job using T-SQL (for example from application/another stored procedure or trigger):

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job N'JobName';
```